# List categories and their products

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using WP e-commerce, I'm trying to print a tree having all categories and products within.
So far, I've only managed to print the categories themselves.

```
<?php wpsc_start_category_query(array('category_group'=>get_option('wpsc_default_category'), 'show_thumbnails'=> get_option('show_category_thumbnails'))); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php wpsc_print_category_url();?>" class="wpsc_category_link <?php wpsc_print_category_classes_section();
        echo 'id';wpsc_print_category_id(); ?>"

        <?php wp_get_object_terms( $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args ); ?>
        <?php title="<?php wpsc_print_category_name(); ?>">
        <?php wpsc_print_category_name(); ?></a>
        <?php wpsc_print_subcategory("<ul>", "</ul>"); ?>
    </li>
<?php wpsc_end_category_query(); ?>
```

Can I somehow mix them together with products?

Comment: For each category you can get the products related and print them. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

see your products are kind of custom posts type so you can display all the categories by [get_categories();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) function it will return an array of all the categories related to some custom post type which is in your case products and with the help of foreach loop and [get_posts(category => $category);](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) you can display different categories and there related posts